# RSS reader and archiver application?

Tags: backup, rss, archive

I am looking for a decent RSS reader app that would double up as an archiver. It would let me flag any posts that I find valuable for PERMANENT storage in a database. Even when the blog is no longer online, this application would let me browse and read the articles I've saved, for YEARS to come.

So I am really looking for the ability to backup RSS posts. Reading offline is only a side effect. I want to be able to flag some of my feeds for permanent storage too, so I don't need to flag each post individually.

Some of the blogs I have been following on personal development topics have a distinct voice and just won't be replaced. Unfortunately, as I have found out blogs (and forums) *do* disappear. And with them, a treasure trove of information that would have continued to be useful to me for years to come.

Does a solution exist on OS X or iOS?

Comment: Does it have to be a single app? I use Reeder and Instapaper and while Instapaper doesn't store things permanently, it does cache things so they're not dependent on a site being up or you even being connected. I've never thought about moving something from Instapaper's cache to a more permanent place but surely its doable by saving things as PDFs locally.

Comment: Yes, I would want to have everything available to read offline as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Newsfire](http://www.newsfirerss.com/) archives entries as long as you want it to.

Comment: Thanks, I have it installed. Had forgotten about that. I guess that's as close as I'll get to what I want.

Comment: Oh I just noticed it also never deletes flagged items, awesome!